# Count Shared Customers

Tags: statistics, puzzle

GIVEN: A company has multiple "retail" locations (10 as an example). They collect data on customers, so they are able to identify customers that shop only 1 location versus customers that shop at multiple locations.

They have a set of data that shows how many customers are shared per site, and how many out of those customers are shared with each additional site.

For example:

Store 1 has 12007, of which 6234 also shop store 2, of which 447 shop store 3 and so on.

Store 2 has 10397, of which 6234 shop store 1, of which 459 shop store 3 and so on.

Here is a grid representing my dataset. The "shared with" columns are shared out of the "shared customers" column, for each row.

To be clear the "shared customers" column contains NO customers that ONLY shop the given location. That means that every one of the 12007 customers from store 1 HAVE in fact shopped one or more of the other stores, and the number of customers out of the 12007 is shown in the "shared with" columns.

[image]

PROBLEM: Based on this set of data, how can I count the number of unique customers within the set? If the company only had 2 locations then this would be easy. Count all from store 1, add store 2 and subtract the number they have in common. However, once you add a third location, I am not sure how to count them, or even if it is possible.

Comment: In your first example - how can there be $500$ out of $400$ customers?

Comment: @barakmanos Please see the grid image I put in the question as an example data set. Hopefully, this helps explain the scenario better. I changed the numbers to reflect the data set.

Comment: You do not have enough information, imagine drawing venn diagrams and trying to extract the information, you can not fill in any area where 3 intersect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.  Suppose you have five stores, each store with six shared customers and sharing three with each other store.  That could come from one customer shared with each other store and two customers who shop all the stores, or from one customer who shops each set of three stores.

Comment: I believe you are correct, but I do want to point something out for the sake of clarity. The "shared customers" column represents the number of folks that are shared with other stores, thus your simple matrix is incomplete as the "shared with" columns summed must be equal to or greater than the "shared customers" column. This may in fact change nothing about your answer, but I figured I should throw that out there just in case.

Comment: I thought the shared customers column included customers that were unique to that store.  In that case I would need another line or two, but the idea is the same.  You can count one person in several different ways.  It is a linear algebra problem to find a distribution of positive and negative customers that adds to zero over the whole matrix, then you can add or subtract multiples of that at will.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect that NO customers are within the shared customers column that ONLY shop one store. Does your answer still hold though? Is it possible to count the customers using just this data set?

Comment: No, see my update. I give an example with only customers shared between stores.

Comment: Thanks! I was suspicious that this was the case, but I needed confirmation from a real Math genius.